# Any optimization for median size spark dataframe join huge dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, left-join

I have a median size dataframe `A` (around 30 million rows) and a huge dataframe(around 20 billion rows). I have to do `A lefeOuterJoin B` operation on some key, let's say `id`.

```
val res = A.join(B, Seq("id"), "left_outer")
```

Here is some more infomation: `id` are nearly distinct in big table B, while there are many duplicate `id` in A(some key may be million size). Direct join A and B is very resource consuming and often lead to failure. So, is there any way to optimize this operation?

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying that there are a lot of distinct values in B (the big dataframe), and much less in A, the medium-sized dataframe. The left join indicates that you are only interested in the small set of keys that are contained in A. You can use that to your advantage by filtering B first.

```
val idsOfA = A.select("id").distinct //very small dataframe
val filteredB = B.join(functions.broadcast(idsOfA), Seq("id"))
val res = A.join(filteredB, Seq("id"), "left_outer")
```

Since there are many duplicates in A, idsOfA is going to be quite small and can therefore be broadcasted. Note that even if you don't broadcast idsOfA, the joins are still going to yield much less shuffle than your previous version.

Comment: Em, it's a great idea. I have tried this, but still get ` Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits` error. Any ideas why this happen?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you do not broadcast the "small" dataframe? If so, can you copy paste the full error trace, and let us know about the size of your executors?

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. I have tried `val res = A.join(broadcast(filteredB), Seq("id"), "left_outer")`, since `filteredB` is not too big, it becomes faster and no memory issue any more.